# Python list transformation

Tags: python, list

I have a list in the following format

```
[Data(Id=1, value='abc', ratio= 0.1),
Data(Id=2, value='def', ratio= 0.3),
Data(Id=3, value='ghi', ratio= 0.15),
Data(Id=4, value='xyz', ratio= 0.5)]
```

I wonder if there is a pythonic way to transform this list to a list of tuples like below

```
[(1, 'abc', 0.1), (2,'def',0.3), (3,'ghi',0.15), (4, 'xyz',0.5)]
```

I know I can parse each element in the list, but that would be very inefficient, I am looking for a pythonic way with maybe a couple of simple lines.

Comment: What is the `Data` class or function? You need to give complete details in a question like this. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "I know I can parse each element in the list, but that would be very inefficient" ... what other choice do you believe you'd have?

Comment: Concur with @juanpa.arrivillaga, there is no way to avoid a loop here. Yet in the space of 10 mins we have 3 identical answers which do just this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objects are `collections.namedtuples`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Data = namedtuple('Data', ['Id', 'value', 'ratio'])
s = [Data(Id=1, value='abc', ratio= 0.1), Data(Id=2, value='def', ratio= 0.3), Data(Id=3, value='ghi', ratio= 0.15), Data(Id=4, value='xyz', ratio= 0.5)]
new_s = [(i.Id, i.value, i.ratio) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'abc', 0.1), (2, 'def', 0.3), (3, 'ghi', 0.15), (4, 'xyz', 0.5)]
```

Comment: If they were `namedtuples`, wouldn't they already *be* tuples?  If so, isn't this an XY problem?

Comment: @SethMMorton `namedtuples` are not tuples, but a subclass of the tuples.

Comment: Of course. But they behave just like tuples. I have a hard time imagining a situation where you needed a tuple and a namedtuple wouldn't also work.

Answer (score 0):

`[(d.Id, d.value, d.ratio) for d in data]`

`data` being your list.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Are you assuming that `Data` is a named tuple?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes.

Comment: while this might work, there is no way to know from the code given if the `Data` class has those fields...

Comment: @Julien True, but in that case the question can't be answered without knowing the details of the `Data` class.

Comment: Then maybe ask for clarification before answering... :)